# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable - Working with Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to convert string values from a column where the values look like this: $200, $6,000, etc. I want to convert these values to float and save them into a new column in my dataframe so I can compute aggregate statistics like .mean() for example.

```
my_df["Float Values"] = my_df["Value"].apply(lambda x: float(x[1:].replace(',','')) if x != "None" else 0)
```

But unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like some of the values in "Value" are already floats, and so `x[1:]` fails for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe there are NaN

use following code:

```
my_df["Float Values"] = my_df["Value"].str[1:].str.replace(',', '').astype('float').fillna(0)
```

---

make reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['$200', '$3,000', float('nan')])
```

s

```
0    $200
1    $3,000
2     NaN
dtype: object
```

run your code:

```
s.apply(lambda x: float(x[1:].replace(',','')) if x != "None" else 0)
```

error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

use following code:

```
s.str[1:].str.replace(',', '').astype('float').fillna(0)
```

out:

```
0     200.0
1    3000.0
2       0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Would NaN give `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` though?

Comment: @slothrop becuz NaN is float

Comment: Oh yes you're right, that's very plausible.

Comment: @PandaKim thank you very much, it worked! It is interesting that the string "None" is seen as NaN

Answer (score 0):

Although the code here is not very much pythonic, a quick solution is to put another line before your mentioned operation. It will convert your column into string from float.

```
my_df["Value"] = my_df["Value"].apply(str)
```

For more, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What is not pythonic about this line of code?